# What does と言ってしまった　mean?

Tags: grammar

> この前、大嫌いと言ってしまったのに*。

Translated as:

> Even though I told him that I hate him so much.

I understand most of it except for しまった。Looks like a verb in past form, しまる? 閉まる? That doesn't seem to make sense.

*from [nihongonomori](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P8papSTl6Ag&list=PLINFE8v4DOhsq0scG83kB5CRnowYWGSH7&index=12).

Comment: See [Unintended Actions](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/unintended) in "Tae Kim's Guide to Learning Japanese"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe it's a past form of しまう. In this case it adds a sense of regret to the phrase. ("He sent me a present... And I told him that I hate him before... That was so wrong of me!") Here is the first article on the topic that popped up in Google: [Using ~てしまう to express regret or completion of something](http://languagesareweird.blogspot.ru/2011/10/using-to-express-regret-or-completion.html).